# Error when testing Promise that contain .catch() methods

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, promise, mocha.js

I have an Angular1 Controller that calls a Service which returns a promise.  When adding a `.catch()` method to the controllers call to the service, mocha throws the following error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'DogService.getDogs(_this.userId)
            .then(function(result){
              _this.myDogs = result;
            })
            .catch') in app/scripts/controllers/main.js (line 20)
    init@app/scripts/controllers/main.js:20:11
    test/spec/controllers/main.js:33:20
    loaded@http://localhost:8080/context.js:151:17
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('testProblemApp').controller('MainCtrl', ['DogService', function (DogService) {
var _this = this;
_this.myDogs = [];
_this.userId = 1;

_this.init = function(){
  DogService.getDogs(_this.userId)
    .then(function(result){
      _this.myDogs = result;
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
};
}]);
```

**Test**

```
describe('initialze function', function () {
it('should set the myDogs array to the value returned by the Service', function () {
  spyOn(DogService, 'getDogs').and.callFake(function () {
    return {
      then: function (callback) {
        return callback([{ id: 1, name: 'baxter' }]);
      },
      catch: function(callback){
        return callback('Error');
      }
    }
  });
  MainCtrl.init();
  expect(MainCtrl.myDogs).toEqual([{ id: 1, name: 'baxter' }]);
});
});
```

If I remove the `.catch()` from the controller the test passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is chaining. It is expected that `then` will return a promise object that has `catch` method. While `then` in `getDogs` mock returns `undefined`.

It is inconvenient to mock promises or other core features with custom stubs written from scratch. `$q` promises can be tested with `$q` promises:

```
var dogsPromiseMock;
...
spyOn(DogService, 'getDogs').and.callFake(function () {
  return dogsPromiseMock;
});
...
dogsPromiseMock = $q.resolve([{ id: 1, name: 'baxter' }]);
MainCtrl.init();
$rootScope.$digest();
expect(MainCtrl.myDogs).toEqual(...);
...
dogsPromiseMock = $q.reject();
MainCtrl.init();
$rootScope.$digest();
expect(MainCtrl.myDogs).toEqual(...);
```

As a rule of thumb, it is preferable to mock services fully when testing controller units, not just mock single methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help!